# how to vsync winapi drawings

Tags: winapi, graphics, 3d, 2d

I want to draw a frame number on my monitor screen sequentially

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...

One number per one physical frame (100 times per second
on 100 Hz refresh rate monitor) Is it possible under
winapi/gdi? How to do it?

Comment: 100 times per second - this will be impossible to see. Anyway, vsync solution exists only in DirectX and OpenGL. Maybe also in Direct2D - I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Neither GDI nor GDI+ give you access to the vsync signal.

The deprecated DirectDraw APIs had a way to wait for the vsync.  Newer DirectX APIs basically do it for you when you call the appropriate Present method (though I believe there are options to *not* wait for the vsync).

Comment: Could you explain "the appriopriate Present method" - I do not understand it. How to do a thing, I asked for: "1" on first monitor frame "2" on the secont and so on...? Under GDI I use blitting call but my prog generates 1000 fps sometimes and 900 of it are wasted :/

Comment: Anything more than ~50fps is wasted anyway as Humans can't see it.

Comment: @Deanna:  It's not that clear cut.  See http://www.100fps.com/how_many_frames_can_humans_see.htm .  And they point may not be for human consumption.  Perhaps it's for making some timing display that will be captured by a high-speed camera.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of have the Desktop Window Manager (a compositor. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager). You can ask it to block until "some event" occurs that is sync'd to the video frame rate. Just call DwmFlush(). I won't link to the docs because the link will go stale.

On my machine, my app is descheduled while waiting for DwmFlush(). In other words it doesn't waste CPU cycles busy-waiting, which is nice.

I believe Windows Vista and 7 had the DWM, but it could be disabled. On Windows 8 and above it is always present.